# how to get none related objects of Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

I have `user` and `news` table and then a middle table called `news_user`, the middle table determines which news has been seen by the user. I can easily get objects that have been seen but, but now I need to show the user objects that have not been seen.

I did a workaround with putting all the seen `news` id in an array and look for `news` where `id` differs from the array. but I don't consider it as the healthiest solution.

This is what I did:

```
$seenNewses = DB::table('news_user')->where('user_id', Auth::id())
->pluck('news_id')->toArray();

$notSeenNewses = News::whereNotIn('id', $seenKeepers)
->orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();
```

Is there a way I can do this with a single query?

P.S: I have seen similar questions but they got little confused. Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: I would start here instead: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

First in your News Model you need to make relationship like this

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(News::class,'news_user','news_id','user_id');
}
```

Below command will give you all the news which are not seen by any users yet

```
$notSeenNewses = News::doesntHave('users')->get();
```

If you want to put any condition then also check for

```
$notSeenNewses = News::whereDoesntHave('users', function ($query) {
    $query->where('YOUR CONDITION');
})->get();
```

It's not tested but you can modify as per your need.

Comment: But I'm looking for the specific user, not just any user.

Comment: So you will have specific news for particular users? Is it your case? Because if then news is common for all users then above code should work